# Obtaining Regression sum of squares for a partial model

Tags: regression, linear-regression

If $SSTO$ = $11489$, $SSE(X1, X2, X3)$ = $335$, $SSE(X1, X2, X4)$ = $990$, and $SSR(X1, X2)$ = $10493$,
I want to find the value of $SSR(X4| X1, X2)$

I know that $SSR(X4| X1, X2)$ = $SSR(X1, X2, X4)$ - $SSR(X1, X2)$. I'm now faced with the problem of finding $SSR(X1, X2, X4)$. 
How may I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that any regression that contains an intercept term satisfies the orthogonal decomposition of the total sum of squares, i.e., the model
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1i}+\beta_1x_{2i}+\beta_1x_{3i}+\epsilon_i,
$$
satisfies $\text{SST} = \text{SSE}+\text{SSR}$, thus
$$
SST=11489 = SSE(X_1, X_2, X_4) + SSR(X_1, X_2, X_4) = 990 + SSR(X_1, X_2, X_4),
$$
hence, 
$$
\text{SSR}(X_1, X_2, X_4)=10499.
$$